# Conditional Probability and Maximum values of random variables including a Geometric Random Variable

Tags: probability, conditional-probability

Let X1, X2, . . . be i.i.d. random variables with the common CDF F , and suppose they are independent of N, a geometric random variable with parameter p. Let $M = max\{X_1, ..., X_N \}$.

(a) Find Pr{M ≤ x} by conditioning on N.

(b) Find Pr{M ≤ x|N = 1}.

(c) Find Pr{M ≤ x|N > 1}.

---

Could anyone explain why in (c) $Pr\{M ≤ x|N > 1\}=F(x)Pr\{M\leq x\}$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have solved (a) and (b) then you can find the answer of (c) on base of the equality:$$P\left(M\leq x\right)=P\left(M\leq x\mid N=1\right)P\left(N=1\right)+P\left(M\leq x\mid N>1\right)P\left(N>1\right)$$

---

**edit**:

I found $$P\left(M\leq x\mid N>1\right)=\frac{pF\left(x\right)^{2}}{1-\left(1-p\right)F\left(x\right)}$$
and: $$P\left(M\leq x\right)=\frac{pF\left(x\right)}{1-\left(1-p\right)F\left(x\right)}$$

showing that indeed:$$P\left(M\leq x\mid N>1\right)=F\left(x\right)P\left(M\leq x\right)$$

Comment: thx, that is a way to calculate (c)

Comment: I have added my own solution.

Comment: Your solution is correct, thank you very much

Comment: Actually the equality can be solved in a more elegant way. After one failure the process starts over and we are dealing with $\max (X_1,N) $ where $X_1$ and $N$ are independent and $N$ has the same distribution as $M $. Then the CDF will be the product of the CDF's of both rvs.

Comment: That's even better, but may I know why there is one failure considered? I think N only relates to the number of r.v. without showing success/failure.

Comment: In my former comment I used $N$ as notation for another rv and overlooking that  $N $ was in use already.  To avoid confusion it must be changed into e.g. $K $

Comment: "At least one failure" would be a better expression. It corresponds with condition  $N>1$ and implies that the first is a failure. That opens the door for writing $M=\max (X_1,K) $.

Comment: To explain that in another way, we've got $Pr(M\leq x)$ in (a), which is actually independent of $N$. Then, $Pr(M\leq x|N>1)$ actually means $X_1\leq x, max\{X_2,X_3,...,X_N\}\leq x$